# Is there anything potentially wrong with this autoRelease usage?

Tags: ios, uilabel, autorelease

Or alternatively: how could this UILabel usage possibly generate an NSMutableDictionary NSInvalidArgumentException?

This is a non-ARC iOS app. When showLabel (below) runs, I will occasionally, but very rarely, see [__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] throw an error: NSInvalidArgumentException *** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myLabel;
@synthesize myLabel = _myLabel;

- (void)showLabel{

if (self.myLabel) {
    return;
}

self.myLabel                        = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame] autorelease];
self.myLabel.textColor              = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myLabel.shadowColor            = [UIColor blackColor];
self.myLabel.shadowOffset           = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
self.myLabel.textAlignment          = UITextAlignmentCenter;
self.myLabel.text                   = @"blah";
self.myLabel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.myLabel addGestureRecognizer:[[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(labelTapped:)] autorelease]];
[self.view addSubview:self.myLabel];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.myLabel];

}

- (void)hideLabel {
if (!self.myLabel) {
    return;
}

[self.myLabel removeFromSuperview];
self.myLabel = nil;

}
```

If I break on [__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:], it is getting called within UILabel's setTextColor, setShadow, setShadowOffset, and setTextAlignment methods. None of the values I'm sending should ever be nil, but this dictionary usage is internal to the label, so I'm wondering if perhaps I'm losing reference to the label after sending autorelease due to some other event causing the autorelease pool to drain while I'm still in my method (there are multiple external libraries involved in the app), and the internal dictionary usage occasionally runs into the error because of that.

Could that possibly explain NSMutableDictionary's NSInvalidArgumentException errors in this case?

Here's the full stack trace:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException *** setObjectForKey: key cannot be nil

1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x3678c963 objc_exception_throw + 31
2 CoreFoundation 0x378625ef -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 143
3 MyApp 0x000effab -[TableViewController showLabel] (MainTableViewController.m:222)
4 CoreFoundation 0x37851349 _CFXNotificationPost + 1421
5 Foundation 0x37b2d38f -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 71
6 MyApp 0x000d9141 -[Event setDictionary:] (Event.m:123)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can safely say that it has nothing to do with the autorelease. Your property has a retain, and you are correctly using the property when storing the variable, so your retain counter goes +1 (alloc) +1 (property setter retain) and eventually -1 (autorelease)

Your problem is probably elsewhere, but I can't figure it out without more code, sorry!

Edit: If you want to play super safe (and I would actually recommend this), you can do like this:

```
self.myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:self.tableView.frame];
// configure
[self.myLabel release];
```

same goes for your gesture recognizer

Try it and see if you still get the crash

Comment: I added the stack trace, if that helps. There is a lot of dictionary usage elsewhere (including the event which triggers this method call, which happens via an NSNotifiation), but within the showLabel method listed in the trace, the label configuration methods are the only ones that show dictionary usage.

Comment: In case you haven't, go to your breakpoints tab on XCode, click the Add `(+)` button on the lower left, select `Add Exception Breakpoint...` and click `Done`. It will tell you exactly in what line it crashes and what's the state of your controller at that moment. The code looks fine so I've no idea what it could mean

Comment: It's too rare for me to catch it in the debugger. So far it only happens in the field. Thanks for the help! Happy New Year :)

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to help you, happy new year!

Comment: I guess a related question is: is it possible for this stack trace to occur if the error wasn't actually happening within showLabel? For example, if it was really a problem in setDictionary, before showLabel is called?

Comment: Well, reading this again, the problem is that you have some `NSDictionary` somewhere that you are treating as an `NSMutableDitionary` ... do you have any processes in other threads? check if you have any `NSMutableDictionary` somewhere that you are assigning a simple `NSDictionarys`

Comment: There is a lot of web API usage elsewhere in the app (though it seems to be all on the main thread), and it's possible we could bet getting an erroneous nil value on occasion, especially upstream in the setDictionary method (which triggers some under-the-hood NSMutableDictionary usage for some date conversions). I'm just unsure of how reliable the stack trace ordering is, when it points to the showLabel method.

Comment: Maybe there are other threads running and it's just a matter of timing and some coincidence that it's happening at that time. There isn't many more options really, the crash is very basic. Depending on how large your code base is, you can check manually if some part can be getting a nil key when setting an object